# Dynamodb - get all the items using IN operator ['shirt','pant'] , Js

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, in-operator

```
const getItemDetailsInCart=(products)=>{
  const items={};
  Object.keys(products).forEach((item,index)=>{
    items[`:${item}${index}`]=item;
  });
  var getCartDetailParams = {
    TableName : "BorderFreeProducts",
    FilterExpression : "Id IN ("+Object.keys(items).toString()+ ")",
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{}
  };
  getCartDetailParams['ExpressionAttributeValues']=items;
  return ddb.scan(getCartDetailParams).promise();
}
```

I have written scan like this , but if the number of products are increasing , processing the params will increase. Is there any other way apart from IN operator which will solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb, scanning your table is almost always a terrible idea. Performances are not guaranteed (they *will* be bad for large tables), and it's very expensive. DynamoDB is just not designed with scanning in mind

In your case, it looks like you are looking for [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) (assuming the `Id` your are mentioning is your primary key), where you can use a single query to get a lot of items from the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Global Secondary Index, say `id-index`, whose partition key is the `Id` attribute, then issue multiple queries, one per ID. This will prevent you having to scan the entire table, which is inefficient if you only want a subset of the items.

Here's an example:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const client = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "us-east-1" });

(async () => {
  const ids = ["shirt", "pant"];
  const promises = [];

  ids.forEach(id => {
    promises.push(
      client
        .query({
          TableName: "BorderFreeProducts",
          IndexName: "id-index",
          KeyConditionExpression: "#id = :id",
          ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#id": "Id" },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":id": id },
        })
        .promise()
    );
  });

  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(results.map(result => result.Items).flat());
})();
```